# Should I always expect the IPFS objects to arrive in .tar.gz format?

Tags: http, format, ipfs

As per [the documentation](http://docs.ipfs.io.ipns.localhost:8080/reference/http/api/#api-v0-get), it is possible to specify a `archive` and a `compress` input variables, but regarless what I put there, when I try downloading something:

```
# Some sample file:
curl -X POST "http://localhost:5001/api/v0/get?arg=/ipfs/QmQPeNsJPyVWPFDVHb77w8G42Fvo15z4bG2X8D2GhfbSXc/security-notes&compress=false" --output ~/Desktop/security-notes.tar.gz -vv

# Some sample directory:
curl -X POST "http://localhost:5001/api/v0/get?arg=/ipfs/QmQPeNsJPyVWPFDVHb77w8G42Fvo15z4bG2X8D2GhfbSXc&compress=false" --output ~/Desktop/whole-folder.tar.gz -vv
```

I always get the same: a tar.gz file (different, in both cases).

Actually, this is what I would expect: To get those files compressed so the workflow is always the same. I can decompress it on arrival. However, the arguments seem to be ignored at all (compress, archive). My question is: should I always expect like this (the contents always arriving as .tar.gz), and not take into account the args in the documentation?

(notes: it is documented that the Content-Type always arrives as text/plain, and this is true in the implementation - I cannot play with the presence of such header)

IPFS version: 0.12.0-rc1